# Padding, Margin, default color are not working tailwind + daisyui

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13, daisyui

I use a next.js 13 project with app directory and tailwind + daisy UI config. padding, margin and colors are not working.

```js
const ContactUs = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="h-full m-2 bg-red-400">
        <div className="bg-primary">this is contact us</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

tailwind.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./utils/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
  daisyui: {
    themes: ["light", "night"],
  },
};
```

postcss.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

global.css

```css
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

After changing **postcss.config.js** margin and padding problem fixed but color are not working.

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: ["tailwindcss", "autoprefixer"],
};
```

I think the problem is in the **tailwind.config** because I didn't extend the daisy ui theme from the main tailwind them but I don't now how to do that.

Comment: Consider checking the `content` file globs sufficiently cover the source code files that uses Tailwind class names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}"` add this to content.

if you are using src directory `"./src/**/*.{ts,tsx}"` add this

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}","./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}", "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./utils/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
  daisyui: {
    themes: ["light", "night"],
  },
};
```